# Toon Outline Not Following Armature

Tags: modifiers, rigging, armature, shaders, toon-shading

I've been building my own character mesh and following the Lightning Boy Studios videos on Youtube to try to create my own toon shader/outliner. For the outliner, I'm using a solidify modifier with a black emission material and backface culling enabled. Everything was going fine until I added a few armature bones just to do a preliminary check on how the mesh would behave under animation. When I moved the armature, the main mesh followed the armature, but the solidify outliner didn't follow at all (see reference image). I'm using automatic weights for the armature. My solidify modifier has already been applied. When I go into weight painting, I can't seem to be able to apply weight to the outline. I'm not sur how to fix this issue to allow the outline to move with the rest of the toon-shaded mesh. Can anybody help me solve this?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: My guess would be that the Solidify modifier was before the Armature modifier on the stack. But you wrote that you have already applied the Solidify modifier. How many character meshes (objects) do you have? According to the screenshot, the base mesh is deformed by the armature but the outline not?

Comment: I thought the same about the modifier stack, but, like you, I figured it wouldn't be an issue if the modifier was already applied. The base mesh for the torso, arms, hands, legs, and feet are all one object. The head, eye, nose, hair, teeth, tongue and eyebrow are separate, but as you can see, the issue is present with a part of the mesh that is a single object. Yes, base mesh is deformed but the outline is not.

Comment: I'm inclined to think this is a glitch that is occurring due to my having applied the solidify modifier. I'm not sure how to fix this now besides rebuilding the entire mesh, though, which is very unfortunate.

Comment: can't you just delete the outline and add the solidify modifier again?

Comment: Tried that. If I add the solidify modifier again, it behaves like I want it to....but...it seems that when I applied the solidify modifier, it permanently created some mesh that is a part of the model. basically I get the result I want plus this extra mesh from the applied solidify modifier. I'm not sure how to get rid of those faces, as when I enter edit mode, the mesh I don't want snaps to the mesh I do want, and I can't figure out how to separate them other than with the armature (as pictured).

Comment: The armature modifier has 4 icons right next to its name. If you activate the *On Cage* and *Edit Mode* (the first 2 icons) then you can edit the deformed mesh. Also, it looks like it's loose mesh. You can select a vert and then press L to select all linked vertices automatically. Maybe this helps you to get rid of the unwanted mesh?

Comment: wow! that's a great idea. it worked well up until pressing L. I guess because the solidify modifier is applied, it views those verts as connected to the same mesh (which is super confusing since it's not behaving like the rest of the mesh in animation ???). I'm worried that if I proceed this way, it may take a while to move the mesh around to try to get all the verts deleted, and I'll inevitably miss some, too. wondering if this is the better approach or simply starting over since it's a relatively simple mesh to begin with. thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you're creating a toon-shaded character with the backface culling solidify modifier for an outliner....don't prematurely apply the solidify modifier to your mesh, or you could run into this issue too once you start animating. just leave the solidify modifier unapplied and make sure it's in the right place in your stack relative to your armature modifier, and you'll be much better off. Thanks for your help in talking through this, Blunder!